# Read numpy array with double brackets

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-io

My data file ('data.txt') is a direct copy-paste from a numpy array output like:

> [[ 1.62434536]\n [-0.61175641]\n [-0.52817175]\n [-1.07296862]\n [
>   0.86540763]\n [-2.3015387 ]\n [ 1.74481176]\n [-0.7612069 ]\n [ 0.3190391 ]\n [-0.24937038]\n [ 1.46210794]\n ... ]]

I would like to read it into a numpy array or panda Serie.
I tried

```
np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter = '\n', unpack = True)
```

I got

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: [[ 1.62434536]

Then I tried

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
data_txt = f.read()
data_txt = data_txt.replace('[', '')
data_txt = data_txt.replace(']', '')
np.loadtxt(StringIO.StringIO(data_txt), delimiter = '\n')
```

It works, but it feels ugly. I wonder if there are more elegant way to just read the numpy array as it is.

Comment: Not sure whether that is more elegant, but you could use the `converters` keyword of `loadtxt`.

Comment: That's an  awkward form to use.  The [] get in the way of CSV reading, and lack of `,`  make it a harder format read as valid Python.  A `tolist()` print is easier to copy and past.

Comment: Right. This is the input for an assignment, so I couldn't choose the data format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence of `[]` and lack of `,` makes normal parsing of this kind of string awkward.  More than once, when copying from a SO question I've just bitten-the-bullet and edited the paste so it will parse.

Use of `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt` requires removing the `[]`.  Parsing as a list requires adding `,`.

In this example, replacing the `\n` with `,` is easy.  If there were multiple numbers per line it would take more work, replacing the w/s with `,`.

```
In [252]: txt="[[ 1.62434536]\n [-0.61175641]\n [-0.52817175]\n [-1.07296862]\n [ 0.86540763]\n [-2.3015387 ]\n [ 1.74481176]\n [-0.7612069 ]\n [ 0.31 90391 ]\n [-0.24937038]\n [ 1.46210794]]"
```

To get this `txt` right I had to edit out the ellipsis.  Here it's from your paste, but in a real world it could part of the array display.

```
In [253]: txt1=txt.replace('\n',',')
```

Once I have `,` delimited data I can parse it as a list in several ways, and having done so create an array.

```
In [254]: eval(txt1)
Out[254]: 
[[1.62434536],
 [-0.61175641],
 [-0.52817175],
 ...
 [1.46210794]]
In [255]: np.array(_)
Out[255]: 
array([[ 1.62434536],
       [-0.61175641],
       ....
       [ 1.46210794]])
```

In some contexts `eval` is too powerful.  `json` is a safer list parser:

```
In [256]: import json
In [257]: json.loads(txt1)
Out[257]: 
[[1.62434536],
 [-0.61175641],
....
 [1.46210794]]
```

as is a function in the `ast` module:

```
In [258]: import ast
In [259]: ast.literal_eval(txt1)
Out[259]: 
[[1.62434536],
 [-0.61175641],
  ....
 [1.46210794]]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want.
So '_'
 means last output?

Comment: It's common for interactive shells to save the last output in a variable named `_`.  I'm using `ipython` which does that and more.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit of a hack, but you could use regular expressions (RegEx), which, as its name implies, helps you find your data in recurring strings. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import re

nptxtarray = '[[ 1.62434536]\n [-0.61175641]\n [-0.52817175]\n]]'
regex = "\D\d.\d{8}"
my_nparray = np.array(re.findall(regex, nptxtarray), dtype=np.float)
print my_nparray
[' 1.62434536' '-0.61175641' '-0.52817175']
```

I know that regex here seems scary, but it's actually very simple once you realize that you are "coding" what you are looking for.

i.e. in our case:

- \D - denotes any non-digits (negative signs, whitespace)
- \d - denotes any digit
- . - ...the decimal point
- \d{8} - is for the trailing decimal numbers

Of course, this might not be the best answer, but it should provide you with another tool which has helped me tremendously in the past. You can learn more and test live at https://regex101.com

Comment: Thanks Leonardo. I do use regexp sometimes. I just imagined since this is the output of numpy, there might be a function I don't know of that directly "takes it back".

Comment: @flyerwolf Have you tried [np.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [np.load](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load)? np.save in particular has an example that might help you

Comment: I know of that. I think it uses pickle right? It it were up to me I'd just use load and save.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are writing this code which you consider to be inelegant to solve a problem with the data that is formatted from your numpy array output.  You don't mention how this data is coming to you, but it might be more "elegant" to format the data when data.txt is written.  Perhaps with array2string()? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html

Comment: This is actually from an assignment. I got the data like that. I do understand we should usually use pickle or some other formats without the brackets to save numpy arrays.